# discord.js How would I get a member in a guild the bot isn't in?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

How would I get a member from a different server that the client isn't in? For example, say I wanted to see if a member has a specific permission in a different server.

Comment: Don't think it's possible

Comment: As everyone else pointed out, it is impossible to get a `GuildMember` if your bot is not in the required `Guild`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that is impossible

However, to get the permission of a user in a guild the bot *is* in, you would use:

```js
client.guilds.cache.get(guildID).members.cache.get(userID).hasPermission(permission) // example permissions enclude: MANAGE_SERVER, MANAGE_EMOJIS, etc.

// returns boolean
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I'm a bit late but is there any way to get the member count of a guild that the bot isn't in?

Comment: Unfortunately not, your bot does not have any data for guilds it's not it.